# Can Beast Boy turn into other humans?

Tags: dc, super-hero, dc-animated-universe, teen-titans, beast-boy

This question could apply to any superhero who can turn into animals, although the only ones who come to mind are Beast Boy and the woman from the Wonder Twins. To avoid making the question too broad, I will focus on Beast Boy.

He can turn into animals. People are animals. So can he turn into other people?

Comment: If he could, they'd still be green. Not that good of a disguise.

Comment: @cde - if he learned to vomit on command, he could copy someone and pretend they had food poisoning or motion sickness or something.  Greenness explained.  You're welcome, Beast Boy.

Comment: Or he could do a crossover with Marvel and copy the green Hulk.

Comment: Or just hang out with Daredevil.  He's blind, he won't notice the green skin.

Comment: That said, Beast boy can copy earth and alien animals, extinct and fictional, change their size, selectively change parts, and can do multiple animals like a swarm of bees. But they are all generic copies, he doesn't copy specific individuals. He probably could do sentient humanoids, but he just doesn't try. No explication. All in his head.

Comment: I'm reminded of the time Marvel's Impossible Man had a shape-shifting fight with the New Mutants' techno-organic Warlock. Impossible Man conceded the battle after Warlock demonstrated the ability to change his color.

Comment: If Beastboy can change into alien races, then maybe he can become a shapeshifting Durlan, like Chameleon boy. In that form he could then become anything or anyone.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**It doesn't appear that there is any reason he can't shape shift into other humans, albeit green ones.**

> Beast Boy has the ability to morph and transform into *any* animal that he has seen himself or has seen in an illustration (as is the case when he shapeshifts into an animal such as an extinct dinosaur) [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beast_Boy#Powers_and_abilities)

He also doesn't appear to be constrained by Earth-born creatures, or even by creatures with a certain lower limit of intelligence.

> Beast Boy has also shown the ability more than once to transform into alien animals, including sentient species such as the Gordanians.[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beast_Boy#Powers_and_abilities)

He has total control of his shape shifting abilities.

> Recently he has also shown the ability to partially transform into an animal, such as acquiring octopus tentacles on the lower half of his body, while his upper-torso remains unchanged.[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beast_Boy#Powers_and_abilities)

**So either he can take the shape of other humans, and simply never has (or never has thought to try) or it is an arbitrary constraint imposed by the writers that makes no logical sense.** Unless they don't consider humans to animals...

Now maybe, *maybe*, he can only take one form of a creature he morphs into. One version of a T-Rex, one version of a gorilla, one version of a mouse, and *one version of a human*.

Comment: I can think of a reason (non-canonical speculation) - while he definitely has a wide range of transformation, he may not be able to change individual *features*.  Either from lack of practice or an innate limitation of his power.

Comment: If he can only turn into "one version of a human," logically one would assume that one version is his "normal" appearance.

Comment: Great answer, I'm out of upvotes for today but I will give you one later.  Thanks!

Comment: This is also a question in the game Dragon Age Origins. When asking the shapeshifter in the party if she can change into other humans she responds with something along the lines of the idea that she has one shape per animal, so like your last sentence, one human, one spider, etc.

Comment: In any case, it's a hard, artificial and arbitrary limit. If you can change shape and mass to any other living creature, at a DNA level like beast boy, changing the DNA that controls specific expressions of traits should be possible. If he can do alien, even more so.  If he can do mythological, then they are just @$!#ing with us...

Comment: Oh hey Robin with green skin and green hair!

Comment: It seems like he can transform into any creature except the original (human), as that just brings him back to his normal form.

Answer (score 5):

Wolfman (co-creator of the New Teen Titans) in a [1982 interview](http://www.titanstower.com/comics-journal-79-marv-wolfman-interview/) with Dwight Decker answers this question...kinda:

> DECKER: Can Gar Logan change into absolutely anything and use his animal form for convenience?
>
> WOLFMAN: No. If I understand the character correctly, in terms of his powers, and that’s picking up off the Doom Patrol stuff, he can only change into animals. Yes, I know the next question is, ‘Can he change into a person because a person is an animal?”
>
> DECKER: It would have to be a green person, though.
>
> WOLFMAN: It would have to be a green person.
>
> DECKER: He could probably do Brainiac 5.
>
> WOLFMAN: Yeah, I would tend to doubt it. I would rather keep him as an animal. The original serum that his real father, Mark Logan, created was to solely tie in the genetic code between humans and animals. I assume that’s the only shape he could take. Yes, we have him turning into a Gordanian in issue 24, 25. Some levels, I’ll extend myself, but I won’t have him turn into other people.

Answer (score 0):

The reason as to why Garfield (Beast Boy) is never seen shapeshifting into other humans, although his powers should allow it, is because any human he turns into would be green and there would be no point for him to use that ability unless he was turning into someone like the Hulk.

Comment: By the way Garfield is Beastboy’s real name.

Comment: Can you offer any evidence to confirm this?

Comment: Also, couldn't he just wear makeup?

Comment: @Valorum: Have you ever seen Beast Boy turn into anything that isn't green?

Comment: @Kevin - Yes, on [many many occasions](https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-d981f52774783b31caaf82c716d7aab0-c).

Answer (score 0):

The following panels are clipped from the legendary "X-Men and Teen Titans" (1982) graphic novel.  This "Elseworlds"/"What If?" scenario might therefore not be strictly canon, but the story remained true to the characters.  The panels speak for themselves in that "I can't mimic people".  And then, whatever he turns into is going to be green.[image: Beast Boy looks over at a group of non-human beings. Contemplating the metaphysics of his powers, he strains to mimic them. A close up of the villains pointing, spotting that although he has mimicked them, he is still 'emerald green'. He is blasted by energy and returns to his normal form.]

This next panel comes from "Teen Titans" #15 (1982) which indicates that Garfield going outside the parameters of "animals" requires some intense emotional trauma.
[image: The setting is a futuristic computer hall, wall to wall with dials and screens. A lone figure flees from a bright green serpent (beast boy), snaking around a metal column. The serpent has a frilled neck and dragon like snout.]